# How to sort and extract a list containing products

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, counting

I've some difficulties with lists containing products as elements, e.g. `list = {A B A, A K B, A K R}`, where A and B are from the same 'family', let's call it sector 1, while K and R are from sector 2.

I would like to find a way to sort the `list` according to the occurrence of elements from sector 2.

The desired output should be something like

```
listWith0Sector2elements = {A K B}
listWith1Sector2elements = {A K B}
listWith2Sector2elements = {A K R}
```

my naive attempt (`Count`, `MemberQ`...) unfortunately failed, as I have never had anything to do with products

**EDIT**:

In the end, I would like to have the sorting, but also these different new lists, as explained in my example.

**EDIT 2**:

It's really hard for me to choose, which answer is the right/best one. I think all of them are great. I will go with the one I finally implemented in my own code. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sector2 = {k, r};

list = Inactivate[{a b a, a k b, a k r}, Times]
```

[image]

```
Count[Alternatives @@ sector2] /@ list
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2}
> ```

#### Sorting

```
SortBy[Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]] @ list
```

[image]

```
Reverse[list]
```

[image]

```
SortBy[Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]] @ %
```

[image]

#### Selecting sublists

```
lstW0S2Elements = Select[Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]@# == 0 &]@list  (* or *)

lstW0S2Elements = Pick[list, Count[Alternatives @@ sector2] /@ list, 0]
```

[image]

```
lstW1S2Elements = Select[Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]@# == 1 &]@list  (* or *)
lstW1S2Elements = Pick[list, Count[Alternatives @@ sector2] /@ list, 1]
```

[image]

```
lstW2S2Elements = Select[Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]@# == 2 &]@list  (* or *)
lstW2S2Elements = Pick[list, Count[Alternatives @@ sector2] /@ list, 2]
```

[image]

And using variant of J.M.'s  answer with an alternative specification of keys in `GroupBy`:

```
gb = GroupBy[list, Count[Alternatives @@ sector2]]
```

[image]

```
lstW0S2Elements = gb @ 0
```

[image]

**Update:** If you wish to work with an input list with multiplication already carried out:

```
lst0 = {a^2 b, a b k, a k r}; 

GroupBy[lst0, 
   Count[# /. { Power -> Table, Times -> Flatten@*List}, Alternatives @@ sector2] &]
```

> ```
>  <|0 -> {a^2 b}, 1 -> {a b k}, 2 -> {a k r}|>
> ```

```
sector1 = {a, b};
GroupBy[lst0, 
   Count[# /. { Power -> Table, Times -> Flatten@*List}, Alternatives @@ sector1] &]
```

> ```
>  <|3 -> {a^2 b}, 2 -> {a b k}, 1 -> {a k r}|>
> ```

Comment: The sorting is okay, but I also want to extract that new information in new lists, as explained in my question

Comment: @NathanaelNoir, please see the updated version.

Comment: It works, but has troubles if my list contains expressions like a^2 b^2. Why is that the case?

Comment: @NathanaelNoir, please see the latest update.

Answer (score 4):

First, you must write products with a space, otherwise it is considered a name.  Note that `A A` will be written as A square.

I assume that elements of different sectors or not already ordered alphabetically as in your example (Sector1: A,B, Sector 2: K,R). In this case sorting would be trivial.

To sort lists according to elements of sector 2 we first extract these elements. Then we use `Order` to determine if the products are in order or not.

Now you can sort ascending or descending. For the first case you would have:

```
list = {A K R, A K B, A B A};
Sort[list, Order[Cases[#1, K | R], Cases[#2, K | R]] &]
(*{A^2 B, A B K, A K R}*)
```

For descending sort you would have to change the sign of `Order`:

```
list = {A B A, A K R, A K B};
Sort[list, -Order[Cases[#1, K | R], Cases[#2, K | R]] &]
(*{A K R, A B K, A^2 B}*)
```

Comment: That's a really easy and nice way! Thank you! How could I extract the different cases in that way? I would like to split the list in different ones according to the found ordered structure

Comment: For this you need to give a criterion where to split. E.g. you could put all lists containing no elements of sector 2 in one list. Those with 1 element of sector 2 in a second list e.t.c.

Comment: I've tried to do it with 'Select' and your ordering but it's not working. Do you have an idea to do that fast ?

Comment: What criterion do you need. Counting is easy if there are no repeated elements. But if there are repeated elements, say A A, MMA rewrites this to Power[A,2] what makes counting difficult. Therefore, restrict your criterion to what you really need.

Comment: My criterion is exactly the one that you implemented in your code, but I would like to split it in different new lists. Let's say: a new list with -Order[Cases[#1, K | R]], a new one with Order[Cases[#2, K | R], as in the example in my original question

Comment: Wait, I am talking about the criterion of how to split in different lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117879/discussion-between-nathanael-noir-and-daniel-huber).

Comment: I don't know, if there is some cool build in function to do that, but your sorting just works fine, but my list is very long and I would like to split the list according your sorting. Let's say list1="all products without an element from sector 2", list2="all products with 1 element from sector 2",ist3="all products with 2 elements from sector 2".

Comment: Do you have repeated elements? Like e.g. A A R?

Comment: yes there can be repeated ones

Answer (score 4):

Things are a little easier if you use `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` instead to represent your products (unless you know your products are commutative). Then, it is just a matter of using `GroupBy[]` with an appropriate criterion:

```
sector2 = {k, r};
prods = {a ** b ** a, a ** k ** b, a ** k ** r};

GroupBy[prods, Count[#, x_ /; MemberQ[sector2, x]] &] // KeySort
   <|0 -> {a ** b ** a}, 1 -> {a ** k ** b}, 2 -> {a ** k ** r}|>
```

`SortBy[]` is also usable:

```
SortBy[prods, Count[#, x_ /; MemberQ[sector2, x]] &]
   {a ** b ** a, a ** k ** b, a ** k ** r}
```

Answer (score 3):

If we want to split the result list according to the factors from sector 2, we need to count those factors. When we have repeated factors, MMA represent them as `Power[factor,n]` and we must take care of this.

Toward this aim, we first change the product into a list. Then we replace every power by a list of repeated factors. And flatten out the double lists. Here is the code for this:

```
ClearAll[count];
count[p0_, base_] := Module[{p},
  p = List @@ p0;
  p = p /. Power[x_, n_] :> Table[x, n] // Flatten;
  Count[p, Alternatives @@ base]
  ]
```

`base`is a list of all factors we wish to count, e.g all factors in scope 2.

Having now a counting function we may split the list by:

```
list = {A^2 B, A B K, A B R, A K R, A K K}
base = {R, K};
Split[list, count[#1, base] == count[#2, base] &]
(*{{A^2 B}, {A B K, A B R}, {A K R, A K^2}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Exponent` to count powers:

```
list = {A B A, A K B, A K R};
 
GroupBy[list, Exponent[# /. {K | R -> $x}, $x] &]
(* <|0 -> {A^2 B}, 1 -> {A B K}, 2 -> {A K R}|> *)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list = {A B A, A K B, A K R};
sector1={"A","B"};
sector2={"K","R"};
```

Then define the test:

```
numOfSector2Element[myEl_]:=StringCount[StringReplace[ToString[InputForm[myEl]],{Shortest[l_~~"^"~~n_]:>StringJoin[Table[l,{ToExpression[n]}]],"*"->""}],sector2]
```

Then select the elements:

```
listWith0Sector2elements=Select[list,numOfSector2Element[#]==0&]
(* {A^2*B} *)

listWith1Sector2elements=Select[list,numOfSector2Element[#]==1&]
(* {A*B*K} *)

listWith1Sector2elements=Select[list,numOfSector2Element[#]==2&]
(* {A*K*R} *)
```